How to create Preview function to ModalBottomSheet
I'm trying to create a @Preview function for a ModalBottomSheet in Jetpack Compose, but I'm only seeing a white screen. Here's my SomeModalBottomSheet composable:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SomeModalBottomSheet(
    uiState: MyUiState,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
) {
    Scaffold() {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
            sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = false)
        ) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
                // other inner composable (custom items I built)
            }
        }
    }
}

And here's my @Preview function:
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
private fun MyModalBottomSheetPreview(
    @PreviewParameter(MyUiStatePreviewParameterProvider::class)
    myUiState: MyUiState
) {
    MyTheme {
        SomeModalBottomSheet(
            uiState = myUiState,
            onDismiss = {},
        )
    }
}

I attempted to create a preview function for a ModalBottomSheet composable in Jetpack Compose. My expectation was that the preview would display a visual representation of the ModalBottomSheet with some content inside it from the PreviewParamteuProvider I built (working). Despite setting the initial value of the sheetState and trying to trigger the BottomSheet for another composable preview, I still only saw a white screen, which was not the expected result.

I am seeing the same issue. Sounds like a bug if you're seeing it too.

There have been some issues logged with Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/283843380

rememberModalBottomSheetState sets the initial sheet state to Hidden by default, so it's expected that you don't see it on the Preview. If you want to see it, you can instead try using rememberStandardBottomSheetState and set initialValue to PartiallyExpanded or Expanded.
Alternatively, you can create a SheetState directly.

This does not make the sheet display in previews for me. Maybe it did at some point, but does not seem so on compose bom 2024.09.00

@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
private fun VisibleDialogPreview() {
    MaterialTheme {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = {},
            sheetState = rememberStandardBottomSheetState(
                initialValue = SheetValue.Expanded
            )
        ) {
            // content
        }
    }
}


The content was showing in the preview, but it was in Hidden state.

Just to add to the excellent answer from Amaury here, and give a solution to previewing the content of your dialog without having to use a different kind of state (as I needed to use rememberModalBottomSheetState due to certain features like skipPartiallyExpanded), it's really good practice to separate the actual content of your composables.
It's a pattern one can also use with ViewModels, as having an injected ViewModel in your Composable can also render it unpreviewable.
Step 1 - Hoist all parts that can't be previewed to your root composable (ViewModels, any "states" that don't preview properly):
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyDialog() {

  val viewModel: MyViewModel = koinViewModel()

  val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = true)

  ModalBottomSheet(
    containerColor = Color.White,
    sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
    onDismissRequest = {  }
  ) {
    MyDialogContent()
  }
}

Step 2 - Put all the meaningful content in a child composable:
@Composable
fun MyDialogContent() {
    Column(
      modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(horizontal = 20.dp, vertical = 10.dp)
        .navigationBarsPadding(),
      horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
      verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
      Text("My Dialog Header")
    }
}

Step 3 - Preview your Dialog content, not the root composable:
@Preview
@Composable
private fun PreviewMyDialogContent() {
  Surface {
    MyDialogContent()
  }
}


In general, this is really good practice throughout your projects. After all, do you really need to preview/test how a Material Bottom sheet looks? Or is it your dialog UI contents that matters.
